# Run JS code when user finished typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of `input` fields with the same `class`. When the user finishes typing the `function doneTyping` should run.

I tried this but somehow it doesn't work. 
Can I use one function for all the `input` fields I have?

```
$(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  var timer;
  var doneTypingInt = 5000;

  $('.typing').keyup(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if ($('.typing').val()) {
          timer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInt);
      }
  });

  function doneTyping () {
    console.log('function doneTyping');
  }
});
```

Comment: *"somehow it doesn't work"* is not a proper technical problem description and is virtually meaningless

Comment: how do you know user has finished typing?

Comment: Perhaps all you need is to change `if ($('.typing').val()) {` to `if ($(this).val()) {`

Comment: just remove your `if` block OR add `$('.typing').val().length > 3` condition

Comment: @brk When a key is released it waits 5 sec to check if another key is pressed otherwise it runs the next function

Comment: `if ($('.typing').val()) {` what's this condition for, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to use the [keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) function. Your adjusted code:

```
$(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  var timer;
  var doneTypingInt = 5000;

  $('.typing').keypress(function(event){
    if(timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
    }

    timer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInt);
  });

  function doneTyping () {
    console.log('function doneTyping');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

what you're looking for is [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

`$('.typing').keypress(_.debounce(yourfunc, 3000))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have something wrong in your code, you just have to wait 5 seconds to see the result, and in order to use one function for all inputs with the "typing" class, you should use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method as follows:

**Javascript code:** ([Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqeqmopt/))

```
$(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  var timer;
  var doneTypingInt = 1000;

  $('.typing').keyup(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if ($('.typing').val()) {
          timer = setTimeout(doneTyping.bind($(this)), doneTypingInt);
      }
  });

  function doneTyping () {
    alert('function doneTyping ' + this.val());
  }
});
```